PyTorch TTS producing Illegal CUDA memory access
I am trying to run couqi TTS but when I try to synthesize audio, Illegal cuda memory access appears.

RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA to enable device-side assertions.

Here is the code That I am trying to run
from TTS.tts.configs.xtts_config import XttsConfig
from TTS.tts.models.xtts import Xtts
    
config = XttsConfig()
config.load_json("/path/to/xtts/config.json")
model = Xtts.init_from_config(config)
model.load_checkpoint(config, checkpoint_dir="/path/to/xtts/", eval=True)
model.cuda()
    
outputs = model.synthesize(
    "It took me quite a long time to develop a voice and now that I have it I am not going to be silent.",
    config,
    speaker_wav="/data/TTS-public/_refclips/3.wav",
    gpt_cond_len=3,
    language="en",
)


I am using ubuntu 22, cuda 11.8, torch 2.3.1 and gpu 3090.

